# How to give DataGridView cell intellisense?

Tags: c#, assemblies, intellisense

I'm trying to create entity classes using CodeDOm for a table from SQL server. I have a datagridview of one column to give the list of namespaces to be added to the class. Is there are any way that I can give each cell of the GridView Intellisense so the typing namesapces would be easy?

EDIT:I found a way to get an autocomplete method to the gridview thanks to @yeonho. I used this code to get the namespaces of System.dll:

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("System.dll");
        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

But, Is there any way that i can reference System.dll without copying it to debug folder or giving full qualified path to it?

Comment: search with keywords like: "gridview autocomplete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like this..

```
public List<Type> GetTypesFromAssembly()
        {
            List<Type> listOfAllTypes = new List<Type>();
            Assembly[] allAssembliesInCurrentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            foreach (Assembly assembly in allAssembliesInCurrentDomain)
            {
                listOfAllTypes.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes());
            }

            return listOfAllTypes;        
        }

public List<string> GetSystemNamespaces()
        {
            List<string> namespaces = new List<string>();            

            List<Type> types = GetTypesFromAssembly();

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.Namespace != null)
                {
                    namespaces.Add(type.Namespace.ToString());
                    namespaces = namespaces.Distinct().ToList();
                }
            }
            return namespaces;
        }
```